# sum rows and columns in a table of numbers

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have large and many tables of numbers. Below is just a sample:

```
A 25 27 50 
B 35 37 75 
C 75 78 80 
D 99 88 76
```

I want to sum the rows and the columns in each table for further processing so the output look like this:

```
A 25 27 50 102
B 35 37 75 147
C 75 78 80 233
D 99 88 76 263
234 230 281
```

How can I do it?
I tried `awk` but did not work.

Answer (score 2):

In general case you would need to do:

```
awk '{ sumrows=0;
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        sumcols[i]+= $i; sumrows+= $i 
    }; print $0, sumrows+0
}
END { for (x in sumcols)
         { printf SEP sumcols[x]+0; SEP=OFS };
     print ""
}' infile
```

The `sumcols[i]+= $i` part is summing-up the field's value in same column position; and `sumrows+= $i` is doing the sum in same rows position, then rows print after every line read with `print $0, sumrows`;

and at the `END` loop over the *sumcols* array and use `printf` to print in single line. The `SEP` is setting with the value of default **F**ield **S**eparator for second print to the next in order to add a single space between each.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command :

```
awk '{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3; sum4+=$4} END {print sum2,sum3,sum4}''{print $0, $2+$3+$4}' file
A 25 27 50 102
B 35 37 75 147
C 75 78 80 233
D 99 88 76 263
234 230 281
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines; put( $_, .words.skip.sum) for @a; #rowsums \
           [Z] @a.map(*.words) andthen .skip.map(*.sum).put; #colsums'   file
```

Sample Input:

```
A 25 27 50 
B 35 37 75 
C 75 78 80 
D 99 88 76
```

Sample Output:

```
A 25 27 50 102
B 35 37 75 147
C 75 78 80 233
D 99 88 76 263
234 230 281
```

In the first `;` semicolon-delineated statement, the `@a` array is created by reading in `lines` (Raku's `lines` routine autochomps, removing `\n` newlines). In the second statement, the `@a` array is iterated over using the postfix `for @a` form:  the subject `put`s the `$_` topic variable, followed by `words.skip.sum`, which denotes that whitespace-separated `words` (i.e. columns) have been `sum`-med linewise, `skip`-ping the first (alphabetic) column. (This rowsum is `put` as the last column. FYI `skip` defaults to a parameter of one line/element etc., as in `skip(1)`).

In the third statement, the `@a` array is re-arraanged by `[Z]` pulling off `word` elements of the `@a` array and combining them. Basically this is the equivalent of R's `t()` transform function, which swaps rows vs. columns. From there, Raku's `andthen` control word is used to reload the `$_` topic variable, the first `$_` element (the alphabetic `A B C D` row) is `skip`-ped, the remaining rows are `sum`-med, and `put` on the final line (as column sums).

https://raku.org