# How to group docker stats by container name prefix?

Tags: bash, awk, docker

How to group `docker stats --no-stream` by container prefix, and show the sum of RAM and CPU and network and IO?

If we consider the first two columns of the `docker stats --no-stream` command to be like this:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME
9b0ef23b9c11   CompanyOneDatabase
e8bd20985752   CompanyOneAdminer
0931f3ece839   CompanyOneSite
ecbf58f6373c   CompanyOneApi
61a5c5853061   CopmanyTwoDatabase
545f6f7d6f03   CopmanyTwoAdminer
28c026a8b048   CopmanyTwoSite
358a1791c233   CopmanyTwoApi
e31c842b7a35   CopmanyTwoAdminPanel
e31c842b7a35   CopmanyTwoAdminApi
```

How can get we this result?

```
CompanyOne RAM_SUM CPU_SUM Network_SUM IO_SUM
CopmanyTwo RAM_SUM CPU_SUM Network_SUM IO_SUM
```

From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473644/sum-rows-and-columns-in-a-table-of-numbers) and [awk](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/) I came up with this script, but it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker stats --no-stream | awk '/CompanyOne/  {print $3, $4, $8, $11}' | xargs awk '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        sumcols[i]+= $i; sumrows+= $i 
    }; print $0, sumrows
}
END { for (x in sumcols)
         { printf SEP sumcols[x]; SEP=FS };
     print ""
}' infile
```

Basically I need to do map/reduce in shell. How can I achieve it?

**Update**: This is a real sample from one of our VPS instances. We have replace company names with letters for privacy:

https://textuploader.com/tdftd

Comment: This question is not strictly related to docker, it's more of an `awk` / text parsing question. Please add a real output (even short) that we can use to reproduce. Regarding your awk command, it does't seem like you understand what it's doing. The `xargs` doesn't seem to fit there, and there's unrelated `infile` at the end. What is your knowledge level in `awk`? Just so I'd know what how deep I should explain.

Comment: you showed two columns from the output of the command `docker stats --no-stream`, but you are working in several columns in your awk, please show a complete sample input and your expected output.

Comment: @aviro, I uploaded a sample.

Comment: on a docker note, you can select which field `docker stats` will print. I don't have ready list, but I use `docker ps --no-trunc --format 'IMAGE|{{.Image}}\nPLAYING|{{.Command}}\nPORT|{{.Ports}}\nNETWORK|{{.Networks}}\nCONTAINERNAME|{{.Names}}\nEND.'` as select command to ease further processing. (this `--format` string will not work with stats, I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

count.awk :

```
NF == 1 {
   ram[$1] = cpu[$1] = network[$1] = io[$1] = 0 ;
}
NF > 1 {
   for (r in ram ) 
       if (substr($2,1,length(r)) == r ) {
          ram[r]+=$3 ; cpu[r]+=$4 ; network[r] += $8 ; io[r] += $11 ;
   }
}
END { for (r in ram )
       printf "%-25s %6.2f %6d %6d %6d\n",r,ram[r],cpu[r],network[r],io[r] ; 
    }
```

you need a list of companies l (in your sample )

```
Aaaaaaaa
Bbbbbbbbbbb
Cccccccccc
Ddddddddddd
```

to be called as

```
docker stats --no-stream | awk -f count.awk l -
```

which give

```
Bbbbbbbbbbb                 0.25   1071   1235    360
Aaaaaaaa                    0.27   1118   2674    382
Ddddddddddd                 0.23   1372   3310    432
Cccccccccc                  0.24   1183   2388   1302
```

- you can adjust format string ("%-25s %6d %6d %6d %6d\n") to give more or less space.
- if each companies always has the same list of container, manual list might be avoided.
- as I note in my comment, `docker stats` can be given a format string (`--format="   "`), which will print only desired field.
- depending on your locale, you may need to call awk as `LC_NUMERIC=C awk -f ...`